# Analytic diffeomorphism and complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Be $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $V \subset \mathbb{C}$ two open sets. We say that $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic (in complex sense) if exist a analytic diffeomorphism $\varphi: U \rightarrow V$. Show that $D(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{C}$ don't are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Are you familiar with [Louiville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis))? It says that any bounded entire holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ must be constant. This can help solve this question.